# find similar occurance of string in an array

Tags: php

lets say we got an array of this

```
$t = array('red - blah blah', 'yellow @ blah blah', 'blue > blah blah');
```

How do we find the similar occurrences in that array? In this case, it would be 'blah blah'. Thanks!

Comment: so if you have: 'red - blah blah2' - it will be just `blah` or `blah blah` (without the 2)?

Answer (score 3):

For easy solution, you could try iterating through possible substrings of first string (starting with the longest ones) and then searching for it in other strings; if found, this is your result. This approach will be quite processor-consuming though.

```
$firstString = $t[0];
for ($len = strlen($firstString); $len > 0; $len--) {
    for ($start = 0; $start + $len <= strlen($firstString); $start++) {
        $possibleCommonSubstring = substr($firstString, $start, $len);
        for ($idx = 1; $idx < count($t); $idx++) {
            if (!strpos($t[$idx], $possibleCommonSubstring)) {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        return $possibleCommonSubstring;
    }
}
```

More general discussion, and more efficient solutions, can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem